In the "House Robber" problem, why are there only two available actions and restricted movement?
Consider the House Robber problem:

You are a professional robber planning to rob houses along a street. Each house has a certain amount of money stashed, the only constraint stopping you from robbing each of them is that adjacent houses have security systems connected and it will automatically contact the police if two adjacent houses were broken into on the same night.
Given an integer array nums representing the amount of money of each house, return the maximum amount of money you can rob tonight without alerting the police.
Example 1:
Input: nums = [1,2,3,1] 
Output: 4 
Explanation: Rob house 1 (money = 1) and then rob house 3 (money = 3).
Total amount you can rob = 1 + 3 = 4.
Example 2:
Input: nums = [2,7,9,3,1] 
Output: 12 
Explanation: Rob house 1 (money = 2), rob house 3 (money = 9) and rob house 5 (money = 1).
Total amount you can rob = 2 + 9 + 1 = 12.

The typical dynamic programming solution assumes that, for each house, there are two possible actions: "rob" and "don't rob". Moreover, the solution proceeds either from the left-most house and moves right (bottom-up) or from the right-most house and moves left (top-down).
Here is an example of the top-down approach:
def rob(nums: list[int], i: int) -> int:
    if i < 0:
        return 0
    return max(rob(nums, i - 2) + nums[i], rob(nums, i - 1))

solution = rob(nums, len(nums) - 1)

However, two aspects of these solutions are not clear to me:

Why do all solutions only consist of moving from either the left-most or right-most houses? Why can't the initial chosen house be the one at the center?
Why are the actions on each house either "rob" or "don't rob"? Why can't the action at each time-step be "choose house $i$", where $i$ is a number between $1$ and the number of available houses to rob (the length of nums)?



The problem is just to compute the maximum amount that can be robbed given the problem constraints, there is no inherent notion of in which order you do it. You could indeed take an optimal set of house indices to rob and rob those houses in any possible order. Precisely because of that is that we can think of a robber who would always rob left-to-right, or right-to-left, as that helps with simplifying the code/analysis and it doesn't constraint the sets of houses to rob in any way.

Again, you can think of the problem in many ways, but one that is helpful and useful here is that it suffices to choose, for each house, whether we rob it or not. This doesn't mean that there are not other ways of thinking about the problem that might lead to optimal solutions too. Maybe some clever algorithm starts by thinking about which sets of houses have values adding up to a prime number, who knows. But it is nonetheless true that any optimal solution can be associated to a set of robbed houses, which in turns corresponds to deciding for each house whether its part of that set or not.


